# CDK: aws_cdk.aws_ecs.EcrImage vs aws_cdk.aws_ecs.ContainerImage

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk, infrastructure

What is the difference between using `aws_cdk.aws_ecs.EcrImage` and `aws_cdk.aws_ecs.ContainerImage` to create instances using CDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much.  [ecs.EcrImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.EcrImage.html) specifically represents an Amazon ECR Registry image.  It extends [ecs.ContainerImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.ContainerImage.html) construct, adding only an `imageName` property.

`ContainerImage` has static methods to return non-ECR (e.g. DockerHub) images.  Perhaps confusingly, `EcrImage` inherits these factory methods as well.